# LiveData with flutter

Tags: flutter, android-livedata

I would like to listen to mysql or any database that is hosted on the internet and update my app(probably like a weather app - automatically fetch changes from internet) and not with db like firebase. Is there any way of achieving it?

Comment: You can  constant fetching data through streambuilder or future builder or bloc pattren

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. In general, relational databases are passive. That is, you query them and they respond.
Each different database provider may or may not give you a proprietary method to listen for changes.

Comment: anything like BroadCast Reciever that can be setup?